# Why don't we have free energy generators?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

**Why can't you create energy out of nowhere**

For me it's not enough that a smart guy for hundreds of years said so. Some scientists and religious people said that the earth was flat - untill someone said it wasn't. And we know that it isn't flat, we can prove it. I can prove it.

Do we just say we can't create energy out of nowhere because Newton said so? Is that our argument - and that no one has proven wrong yet? I think you know some kind of mathemagic that proof that Newton is correct; could you please explain it to me?

**What about Vacuum Quantum Fluctuations and the Casimir Effect?**

Is that just a mathematical estimation? Or where do the energy come from? In my (non scientist) eyes it comes like - from nowhere.

**Is a Zero Point Energy Module possible?**

[I have found this article](http://www.collective-evolution.com/2013/10/11/multiple-scientists-confirm-the-reality-of-free-energy-heres-the-proof/). Actually all my questions are based on this article. It would be nice if you take a look on the article and try to explain against it.

In this article on a no-name-blog there is the claim, that a lot of scientists (phds, professors and so on from well known universities) say that such a "free energy generator" is possible, and that it was build. But because companies would lose money, it will never come to society. There is a lot of fancy words in it, a lot of PhD and other titles and sources on like Nature.

Comment: "Zero point energy" is a fantastically bad term for the physical phenomenon to which it refers. There is no energy there. Repeat: zero point energy is not energy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks several vague questions. The post would be much better if it asked a single, specific, clearly worded question.

Comment: Actually I think she ask if such a zero point energy module is possible and why not.

Comment: I think the last 2 questions are good, though perhaps each should be asked individually.   The introduction is a bit strange and shows a lack of research.   "Scientists" never said the earth was flat.  That's a myth.   And conservation of energy isn't because Newton "said so", Newton studied and understood energy very well and his proposed idea of conservation of energy passed numerous tests and study before it was accepted as a scientific law.

Comment: @DanielSank: I think thorough debunking would be better.

Comment: @Gert I agree with you in general that it's best to help OP understand things better, but I also think we should be mindful of our site's quality standards. Asking multiple questions in one post is already shaky in my opinion. This post does several other things which lower the quality: 1) Link to article without explaining relevant points from it, 2) several unfounded assumptions, 3) appeal to authority, 4) what is actually being asked is still unclear (to me). Before I edited the post it contained swear words and tons of irrelevance.

Comment: @DanielSank: very fair points. I'm more worried about this stuff getting google-indexed without a rebuttal.

Comment: There's nothing "mathemagic" about physics. It's an experimental and observational science. Mathematics happens to often be useful to describe and codify observational results, but it is in no way fundamental to physics. The idea of "suppressed technology" is laughable on its face. The world contains too many competing interests for any such attempt to long survive the desire of some corporation or government to gain decisive advantage.

Comment: And, Just to add, the linked article is 100% bunk.   Here's a discussion of it being debunked if the OP is interested:   https://www.metabunk.org/debunked-quantum-energy-generator-qeg-10kw-out-for-1kw-in.t3572/   It's also discussed here:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107347/free-energy-device-qeg-is-this-for-real   I still think zero point energy and vacuum fluctuations and how they apply to conservation of energy is valid to ask, but the idea that somebody's built a small device that does it based on Tesla?  Pure bunk.

Comment: Just a little technical correction: Newton didn't say that energy can't come out of nothing, even though the "vis viva" and its conservation were known since Leibniz, the proper ideas about energy weren't even developed at Newton's time and the naming comes from the early 19th century, which is also when a more thorough understanding of heat and thermodynamics were developed. The perpetual motion business has been around since the Middle Ages, but unlike the goldmaking it didn't die out with the alchemists. It's still a booming business which has rebranded itself into "free energy".

Comment: @Gert Oh my goodness I sympathize. I never used to understand the fervor with which people vote to close until I understood that issue. Remember the availability of the down vote! for answers you think are incorrect!

Comment: What fascinates me here is that you seem to believe both that arguments from physics are bunk *and* that you can make arguments from physics to prove that the world is not flat.

Comment: @userLTK Thank you very much for that link. That is what I've searched for!

Comment: The whole  "people of the middle ages thought the earth was flat" is nonsense and why I refuse to read anything by [Washington Irving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Irving) (he invented the myth for his book *A History of the Life and Voyages of Christopher Columbus*; sadly it's stuck around despite being debunked time and time again).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conservation laws are intimately connected with symmetries. This was proved by a mathematician called [Emmy Noether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmy_Noether) in 1915 and is called (not unreasonably) [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). The only assumption required is that the system can be described with [Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics).

In particular conservation of energy is related to a symmetry called time shift symmetry. This basically means the laws of physics don't depend on what the time is. So given Noether's theorem we know energy is conserved if:

1. time shift symmetry applies
2. all physics can be described using Lagrangian mechanics

Ultimately these two criteria have to be tested by experiment, and so far experiment has failed to disprove them. So the principle of conservation of energy is derived from a mathematical proof backed up by experimental evidence. It is most certainly not just something *that a smart guy for hundreds of years said*.

Since energy is conserved we can't get energy from the vacuum. The question is then why not. The answer is simply that the vacuum is the lowest energy state possible. We can only do work if we can move energy from some higher energy state to a lower energy state. Since there is no energy state lower than the vacuum we can't do any work using vacuum energy.

The article you cite is I'm afraid just one of many based on a misunderstanding of the physics involved. It is certainly true that we can extract work using the Casimir effect, but that's only because the setup of parallel plates involved has a higher energy than the vacuum. We need to put work in to set the system up before we can extract energy from it. The amount of energy that can be extracted is equal to the amount of energy we need to set up the system in the first place, so there is no free energy to be had.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But it would still have been nice if such a mashine would have existed :/